# OpenFOAM and CFDEM on GPU

Tags: fluid-dynamics, gpu, openfoam

I have a simulation project written for OpenFOAM and CFDEM and would like to find an alternative to run it on GPU since raising the number of cores already provided a promising speed up and extrapolation shows that GPU could be the way to go.

For OpenFOAM exists a project called "RapidCFD" which brings OpenFOAM computations to the GPU but it isn't compatible with CFDEM/LIGGGHTS and even porting it doesn't seem very promising referencing the answer of one of the developer (https://github.com/Atizar/RapidCFD-dev/issues/64).

> My suspicion is that will not be easy or efficient to use the RapidCFD base code for a CFDEM solver.
>
> - LIGGGHTS is not GPU enabled, as far as I know.
> - The CFDEM libraries are not setup for GPU calculations.
> - RapidCFD is based on OpenFOAM 2.3.x, and presently CFDEM is based on    OpenFOAM 5.x (maybe the current version of CFDEM still works
>     with OF
>     2.3.x, or for sure you can use an earlier version of CFDEM, to get around this concern).
>
> But the main idea of RapidCFD is to minimize data transfer between CPU
>   memory and the GPU. Without porting the CFDEM libraries (or LIGGGHTS,
>   too?) for GPU, I am not sure this will be as speedy as some of the
>   other results people have discussed with RapidCFD, since data will
>   need to be transferred between CPU and GPU (this is slow).
>
> Finally, I don't think that all calculations lend themselves to
>   speedup on the GPU, even if you were to port CFDEM libraries and/or
>   LIGGGHTS to GPU. One would need to examine if the type of calculations
>   done by CFDEM and/or LIGGGHTS are matrix type calculations that lend
>   themselves to GPU speedup. If not, then after all the work is done,
>   the speedup may not be so impressive.

Another project I found which could probably replace LIGGGHTS is EDEM (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6267572/) and due to the following publication (https://www.edemsimulation.com/news/new-cfd-coupling-interface-for-edem-enables-particle-fluid-simulation-with-any-cfd-software/) it should be possible to couple it with any CFD software.

As I have no experience in the area of CFD and DEM Particle simulations I would like to ask you if you know alternatives and possible expectations for a speed up using those tools. Does it make sense to switch to a commercial tool like EDEM and combine it with an GPU enabled CFD Solver.